# Prove that $R$ given by $L(a,b)\cap W =\varnothing$ is an equivalence relation.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, equivalence-relations

Let $V$ be a real vector space and suppose $W$ is a subspace of $V$ with $\dim(W)=n-1$. Now define a relation $R$ on $V-W$ s.t. $$aRb\iff L(a,b)=\{ra+(1-r)b | 0\leq r \leq 1\}\text{ has the property that }L(a,b) \cap W = \varnothing$$ Prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation.

I am having problem to check transitivity. If $aRb$ and $bRc$ suppose $a$ is not related to $c$, then $\exists t \in (0,1)$ s.t $ta+(1-t)c \in W$. How do I get a contradiction?

Comment: Looks obviously true: there are just two equivalence classes, namely the teo connectec components of V - W.

Comment: Yeah if it is an equivalence relation then we will get exactly two equivalent classes. But algebraically how do we arrive at contradiction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intuition why this is an equivalence relation is, as explained by almagest, that the hyperplane $W$ seperates $V-W$ into two connected components. Two points $a,b\in V-W$ are in the same component if and only if the line segment $L(a,b)$ does not intersect the hyperplane $W$.

For a formal approach, describe $W$ as the kernel of some non-trivial linear-form $\omega\colon V\to\mathbb R$. Now let's translate $aRb$ using this description. Instead of $L(a,b)\cap W=\varnothing$ we can say

> For all $x\in L(a,b)$ we have $\omega(x)\neq 0$.

and even more explicit

> For all $0\le r\le 1$ we have $r \omega(a) + (1-r)\omega(b)\neq 0$.

Now this is a statement solely about the two real numbers $\omega(a)$ and $\omega(b)$. In fact, using the *intermediate value theorem*, you can check that this is equivalent to

> The two non-zero real numbers $\omega(a)$ and $\omega(b)$ have the same sign.

From this the fact that this relation is an equivalent relation becomes obvious.

---

Let me elaborate on the equivalence claimed above.

Suppose $\omega(a)$ and $\omega(b)$ are non-zero real numbers with different signs. Consider the real function $f\colon [0,1]\to\mathbb R$ with $r\mapsto r\omega(a)+(1-r)\omega(b)$. This function is continuous with $f(0)=\omega(b)$ and $f(1)=\omega(a)$. Since $f(1)$ and $f(0)$ are non-zero of different signs, the intermediate value theorem says there exists $r\in(0,1)$ such that $f(r)=0$, hence $r\omega(a)+(1-r)\omega(b)=0$.

Now suppose that $\omega(a)$ and $\omega(b)$ are non-zero real numbers with the same sign. When $\omega(a),\omega(b)>0$, you can conclude that $r\omega(a)+(1-r)\omega(b)>0$ for all $r\in[0,1]$ since products and sums of positive numbers are positive. The same approach works for $\omega(a),\omega(b)<0$.

Comment: Yeah if it is an equivalence relation then we will get exactly two equivalent classes. But algebraically how do we arrive at contradiction?

Comment: You don't need a contradiction if you follow what I explained. If $\omega(a)$ has the same sign as $\omega(b)$ and $\omega(b)$ has the same sign as $\omega(c)$, the signs of $\omega(a)$ and $\omega(c)$ can't be different.

Comment: Sign means you are saying the $\pm$ signs in $\Bbb R$ but is it possible to go in the way, I was trying to prove?

Comment: The sign of a non-zero real number is $+$ when it is $>0$ and $-$ when it is $<0$. I don't think this question has a nice solution without describing $W$ as the kernel of a non-trivial linear form.

Comment: Yeah I have edited my last comment. But the thingh is "I was trying in the direct procedure" but couldn't get contradiction...

Comment: And as you told I was realizing it in $\Bbb R^2$ this thing. But I wanted to prove it directly..

Comment: Nice solution means you are saying that on the other way round the eqn will be complicated??

Comment: There's no way of proving that this is an equivalence relation without the fact that $W$ has codimension $1$, since it is wrong for subspaces of higher codimension. So describing $W$ as the kernel of a linear form is the way to go.

Comment: Okay then can you give me the explicit map $w$ there? Means how can I define $w$?

Comment: Since you have no explicit description of $W$, I can't give you an explicit description of an $\omega$ with $W=\operatorname{ker}\omega$.

Comment: Then are you using the projection concept?

Comment: That $\exists W^"$ s.t $W \oplus W^"=V$, then $ \phi(w+w^")=w$?

Comment: I don't know what that means. I'm using the fact the $V/W$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R$ so the quotient map $V\to V/W$ translates to a linear form $V\to \mathbb R$ with kernel $W$.

Comment: Again in here also I am not getting I should get a map on $\Bbb R$ here..

Comment: Okay I am trying to get your point.

Comment: You could take $n$ a normal vector to $W$ and define $\omega(x) = n\cdot x$ the dot product of $x\in V$ and the normal vector $n$. This map has kernel $W$.

Comment: Yeah this process will work , thanks.

Comment: Yeah in fact you are constructing projection operator... nice concept.

Comment: I added a proof of the claimed equivalence.